# Yours will be the fifth

Tags: riddle, rhyme, rebus

```
"We meet every 65 minutes"
"Nobody wants to experience me"
"I'm a bend, a turn, I'm 5 places from last"
"We're the smallest total we can be"

For the last member of this 5 word phrase
the rebus shows its identity
Using this riddle as your guide for an answer
Can you show me the number that I want to see?
```

[image: a wooden box containing a lower-case version of the 5th letter of the alphabet]

A correct answer requires two parts:

- What sentence does the riddle create?
- The correct number, in respect to the riddle's phrase.

(And for bonus points, where are the other four?)

Hints for word 2:

> -I help you realise you haven't been feeling me when you do
>  -I feature as a feeling in the chorus of a song by Passenger
>  -I'm a bit of wordplay, usually two small words (1, 3), but for this riddle I have five letters

Hints for word 4:

> -We counted everyone here, and sure enough, there couldn't be less of us

Hint for final answer:

> -For the expected solution to the puzzle, you *may* need to upload an image.

Answer (score 5):

Extremely unfinished partial answer:

"We meet every 65 minutes"

> Hands -- the hour and minute hand meet every 65 and 5/11 minutes.

"Nobody wants to experience me"

> Death? loss?

"I'm a bend, a turn, I'm 5 places from last"

> V - A vee is a bend or turn in a road, and the letter V is the fifth from the end of the alphabet.

"We're the smallest total we can be"

> zero?

For the last member of this 5 word phrase
the rebus shows its identity

> The rebus shows an e in a box/carton/crate. Beox? Boex? Careton? Carteon? Create?

Using this riddle as your guide for an answer
Can you show me the number that I want to see?

> hands death vee zero create ???? havoc?

Comment: There are two correct interpretations in here, good start!
I'm thinking I might need to provide some hints for the lines that are a bit vague.

Comment: I'm thinking the third one may actually be rot13("lbh". h-oraq, h-ghea, naq h vf 5 yrggref orsber m)

Comment: The smallest number that can be "we" is two

Comment: Hands ___ you to create

Comment: We're almost there!

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the second word is

> Allow

Because

> Nobody wants to feel a low

I figured this out after extensive clues.

The final phrase is

> Hands allow you to create

Comment: This is the sentence that the riddle creates, well done!
If you can complete the second part of the answer the checkmark is yours!

Answer (score 2):

We're the smallest total we can be

> Two, since anything less would not be "we"

Comment: Dr Xorile made that comment 9 hrs ago

Comment: @j3App Argh, I missed that...

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer for 2 is

> Pain

Comment: I've added new hints for this one, probably the hardest word to get of the lot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is right...

> Hands alone 5 2 create

That would mean the answer is...

> 7

Is that correct?

I was completely stumped on the second word, it was really hard. Thanks @Grumpyllama 59!

Comment: We're very close, but the second and third words aren't quite right.
There's also a few errant hints for the final answer that are yet to be mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I that think word 2 might be

> Alone. No one wants to be alone. Made from two small words all and one. The feeling of Let her go by Passenger.

Then we would have

> Hands alone (I'm not sure of this word) we create

Comment: Honestly, that's really good, and super close (it's even the right song!), but it wasn't quite the word I had in mind.